# Main content and scrollspy navigation columns overlapping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I want to adjust the alignment of two elements: the left hand nav and main content div are overlapping each other. I don't have some specific conditions for them, it just should be next to each other in columns without overlaying.

[image: The left hand of the main content overlaps the left hand navigation so that the section numbers in the nav are covered up.]

Here is the code with both navigation and scrollspy. You will have to run the snippet and use the full page link to see the content.

```js
$(function () 
        {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
```

```css
/* CSS FOR SCROLLSPY */
      body 
      {
        position: relative;
      }

      ul.nav-pills.flex-column 
      {
        top: 20px;
        position: fixed;
      }

      div.col-8 div 
      {
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy" data-offset="1">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About author</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="CCNA 3" 
                    data-content="This course is already in progress. Stay tuned.">CCNA 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>



    <div class="d-none d-xl-block col-xl-2 bd-toc">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
              <div class="col-sm-9 col-8">
                <div id="section1" class="bg-success">    
                  <h1>Section 1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section2" class="bg-warning"> 
                  <h1>Section 2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>        
                <div id="section3" class="bg-secondary">         
                  <h1>Section 3</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
                <div id="section41" class="bg-danger">         
                  <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>      
                <div id="section42" class="bg-info">         
                  <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
                  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**col-xl-2** class causes this overlaying. Remove it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
  /* CSS FOR SCROLLSPY */
  body 
  {
    position: relative;
  }

  ul.nav-pills.flex-column 
  {
    top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
  }

  div.col-8 div 
  {
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
</style>
  
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" style="width:50px;">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-pills">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About author</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CCNA 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="CCNA 3" 
                data-content="This course is already in progress. Stay tuned.">CCNA 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>



<div class="d-none d-xl-block bd-toc">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <nav class="col-sm-3 col-4" id="myScrollspy">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="col-sm-9 col-8">
            <div id="section1" class="bg-success">    
              <h1>Section 1</h1>
              <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="section2" class="bg-warning"> 
              <h1>Section 2</h1>
              <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>        
            <div id="section3" class="bg-secondary">         
              <h1>Section 3</h1>
              <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="section41" class="bg-danger">         
              <h1>Section 4-1</h1>
              <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>      
            <div id="section42" class="bg-info">         
              <h1>Section 4-2</h1>
              <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation list while scrolling!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () 
  {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
</script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```